# Convert C# DateTime to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I have a c# DateTime passed to the client as:
`1980-01-20T00:00:00`

How do i convert it to javascript DateTime? I tried doing

```
var date = new Date(1980-01-20T00:00:00) but this gives me an error
```

Answer (score 3):

Put it in quotes:

```
var date = new Date("1980-01-20T00:00:00")
```

```js
var date = new Date("1980-01-20T00:00:00")
alert(date)
```

Comment: Only problem with this is:This will only work if you know the date format is right.. This works as long as you make sure thats the case.

Comment: @MarkSmit it will be the correct format, always, cause it is the default C# `DateTime` format, which cannot change.

Comment: It actually does change if you avoid your application to use the invariant culture.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the amount of miliseconds from 1970:

```
long epochTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks
long unixTime = ((DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - epochTicks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
long javascriptTyme=unixTime*1000;
```

Thats the value you want to send to javascript